# How to respond to stdin while running another function?

Tags: python, stdin

I am trying to write a python script that will print out text within a loop, and respond to stdin if anything is printed to it. (I am planning to use this python script to interface with another program)

I previously written a script to do this in bash and now want to learn how to do this with python. I used to do this in bash with the following script;

```
#!/bin/sh

get_text () {
    echo "Some stuff here"
}

get_loop() {
    get_text
    /usr/bin/pactl subscribe | while read -r line ; do
        echo $line |
            grep -q -e "sink" -e "'change' on server #" && 
            get_text
    done
}

get_action () {
    case $1 in
        1)  # Left
            /usr/bin/pactl set-sink-mute @DEFAULT_SINK@ toggle > /dev/null 2>&1 ;;
        2) # Middle
            ;;
        3) # Right
            [ -x '/usr/bin/pavucontrol' ] && /usr/bin/pavucontrol > /dev/null 2>&1 & disown ;;
        4) # Scroll Up
            if [ "$_volm" -ge 100 ] ; then
                /usr/bin/pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ 100%  > /dev/null 2>&1
            else
                /usr/bin/pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ +5% > /dev/null 2>&1
            fi ;;
        5) # Scroll Down
            /usr/bin/pactl set-sink-volume @DEFAULT_SINK@ -5%  > /dev/null 2>&1 ;;
    esac
}

get_loop & while read button ; do get_action $button ; done
```

Which works like I intended it to work. So far in python, I have this;

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import time

def respond(x=0):
    while True:
        x += int(sys.stdin.readline())
        print(x)

def loop(t=1):
    x = 0
    while True:
        x += 1
        print('Delay is ' + str(t) + ' and looped ' + str(x) + ' times.')
        time.sleep(t)

loop(1)
respond(0)
```

The functions individually work, but how do I make them work at the same time? I was thinking of making one whil loop, and waiting until event or there is something on the stdin; but can I do that?

(For details on the task I am trying to do, I am trying to write a blocklet for pulseaudio to [i3blocks](https://github.com/vivien/i3blocks). The script prints out a line of JSON formatted text, which is read by the process and the information is printed on my status bar. Every time something changes with pulseaudio, my script prints an updated line. i3blocks also sends a JSON formatted string that is information when a mouse click event happens, for which I decide to toggle mute, increase/decrease volume or launch a program. I do have it working with bash, but I am also learning python and converting my bash scripts to python is a toy project I have to delve into these things.)

Comment: If you want to run two functions at once you can use threads.

Comment: Threading or multiprocessing. Otherwise GIL will stop you from doing that.

Comment: This is what I feared. Is there a way to issue a continue in an infinite loop on some event, or something on stdin?

Answer (score 0):

Your bash file never take any input and neither dose the python file since you have an endless loop and never actually call the respond function.

Comment: I simpified my bash function as a demonstration; I'll update it with the original one.

Answer (score 0):

The `&` in the last line of the Bash script starts `get_loop` asynchronously.  One way to achieve this in Python is the `threading` module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
import time
from itertools import count
from threading import Thread


def respond():
    total_sum = 0
    while True:
        total_sum += int(sys.stdin.readline())
        print(total_sum)


def loop(delay):
    for i in count():
        print(f'Delay is {delay} and looped {i} times.')
        time.sleep(delay)


def main():
    thread = Thread(target=loop, args=[1])
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()
    respond()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Other ways would be using the `multiprocessing` module which can be used to start one of the functions in another process, which is what the Bash actually does with `&`.  Or `asyncio` module and Python's `async`/`await` keywords.